# US Master Admissions, LoR: Academic vs. Employer

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, recommendation-letter

As a matter of recommendation letters, how do US admissions to MS programs *generally* look at LoRs from employers as opposed to those from academics? And how are recommendation letters generally weighted in the application process? I know the paradigm varies by institution, so I'm just looking for an idea.

**Preface**: I worked full-time during my undergraduate studies and admittedly at different jobs, so I feel that I haven't built any particularly strong relationships with faculty at my institution. I do, however, feel that the individuals I've asked to draft letters at my employer could provide reasonably strong recommendations (they are supervisors).

The program itself isn't traditional: It includes an industry internship with a relevant project and paper as opposed to a research/thesis component, though candidates can register for directed research as a part of the electives.

If I can provide any more pertinent information, please let me know!

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/59548/20375

Comment: What kind of MS programs (class-based or research)?  In what subject?  In how strong a department?

Comment: @JeffE M.Sc. Biotechnology, mostly class-based with an internship component instead of research/thesis. Program itself is through our college of medicine, quite a good department in an RU/VH university.

Answer (score 2):

For graduate study, what the committee looks for is primarily ability to do *research*. You need LoRs that highlight that aspect of your work. If no faculty can attest to it (or you in general), a letter from a previous boss at work might do.

Comment: I would almost certainly agree, normally, but from the program documentation below there is no research component to the degree, almost akin to non-thesis MS.

"Students will have to complete a practical internship and theoretical assignment which will both require the successful application of the knowledge they have acquired during their formal training. Required are: (1) an internship with a written and an oral internship report, and
(2) a review paper providing an overview of recent advancements in an area of [industry] of the student's choice."